# React_native Android Application is getting crashed randomly when not connected to React Packager

Tags: android, react-native

When I am running my app by connecting to the react packager server my app is not crashing for any exception . But when i am creating the apk by using generate signed apk my app is crashing by generating the exception like below and displaying the red screen in app.

> E/unknown:React: Exception in native call java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.updateNodeSize(UIImplementation.java:149)at
>   com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerModule.updateNodeSize(UIManagerModule.java:235)at
>   com.facebook.react.views.modal.ReactModalHostView$DialogRootViewGroup$1.run(ReactModalHostView.java:311)at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)at
>   com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176 )at
>   com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:196)at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem, so I just signed app for release and distributed it like that. Everything works fine now.